# How to convert my spatiotemporal NetCDF data to spatial data?

Tags: r, netcdf

I am very beginner in R. and I totally struck with this problem. you can download the netCDF file from link below to take a look.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY3OAw62EShbkF6VWNFUkRYMmM/view?usp=sharing

^This is my NetCDF atmospheric data file with 8 variable and 8 dimension. Here,my variables of interest are:

TIMSID is number of site (its include urban site, rural site etc.)
  URBAN :: number of urban sites  [urban is 3 row 250 column matrix. row1 is number of urban sites , row2 is latidude, row 3 is longitude.]
  TIME :: data was collected from 1 march 2012 to may 2012 [encoding for 'time' is YYYYMMDDHH]
  PM10 :: hourly particulate matter concentration measured at every station of every site

I need to work with only these 4 variables from this large data set.

I have to separate the data of PM10 values only at urban sites only for "1 march 2012". (Actually I need to find in TIMSID variable which sites are urban sites and match the corresponding PM10 value for urban sites only for 01 march 2012.)

For example, in TIMSID, different type of sites exist like urban, rural etc named 111121,111122,111123,111124 but urban site number are 111121,111123..etc so i have to consider only urban site from TIMSID data and want to match the corresponding pm10 value, time, latitude, longitude. And then finally wanna make a new dataset.

The final table/dataset should be ~ column1-time(only 1 march 2012),column2-urban sites number, Column (3,4)-latitude and longitude of corresponding urban sites, Column 5- hourly pm10 value in each urban sites

I have used these following command to read the data from NetCDF file. But I can't understand what should I do further...

```
install.packages("ncdf",dependencies=TRUE)
library(ncdf)

nc<-open.ncdf("2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc")
print(nc)

tmsid<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"TMSID")
timsid

urban<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"urban")
urban
time<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"TIME")

pm10<-get.var.ncdf(nc,"PM10")
```

As I am beginner in R so I only know the basic commands. I can't figure out, which specific package I should learn to solve this problem. Please help me out? Thanks in advance for your valuable time. If you need any further information please ask me anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ncdf)
nc <- open.ncdf("2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc")
tmsid <- get.var.ncdf(nc,"TMSID")
urban <- get.var.ncdf(nc,"urban")
time <- get.var.ncdf(nc,"TIME")
pm10 <- get.var.ncdf(nc,"PM10")
```

First let's have a look at `nc`:

```
[1] "file ~/Downloads/2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc has 8 dimensions:"
[1] "data_num   Size: 683016"
[1] "ncl1   Size: 683016"
[1] "obsnum_urban   Size: 250"
[1] "ID_LAT_LON   Size: 3"
[1] "obsnum_road   Size: 33"
[1] "obsnum_background   Size: 5"
[1] "obsnum_rural   Size: 16"
[1] "ncl7   Size: 683016"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file ~/Downloads/2012_03_05_PM10_surface.nc has 8 variables:"
[1] "int TMSID[data_num]  Longname:TMSID Missval:NA"
[1] "int TIME[ncl1]  Longname:TIME Missval:NA"
[1] "float PM10[data_num]  Longname:PM10 Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float urban[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_urban]  Longname:urban Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float road[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_road]  Longname:road Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float background[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_background]  Longname:background Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float rural[ID_LAT_LON,obsnum_rural]  Longname:rural Missval:1e+30"
[1] "int TMS_JULIAN[ncl7]  Longname:TMS_JULIAN Missval:NA"
```

What it tells us is that `urban`'s rows are ID, latitude and longitude. Then we have `tmsid` giving the vector of IDs of same size as the vector of `time`: one per `data_num`, i. e. one couple ID-time per datapoint in `PM10`, meaning we will be able to subset `pm10` by IDs (which are given by the first row of `urban`) and by timestamp (from 2012030101 to 2012030124).

```
# First we need to make a dataframe out of urban, for convenience.
urban <- as.data.frame(t(urban))
colnames(urban) <- c("ID", "LAT", "LON")
# Then we do the subsetting using a lapply, so we can batch-subset:
res <- lapply(urban$ID, 
              function(x)data.frame(ID=x,
                                    pm=pm10[tmsid%in%x & time%in%2012030101:2012030124], 
                                    time=2012030101:2012030124))
# Which gives us a list of sub-dataframes that we want to compress back into a single dataframe:
res <- do.call(rbind,res)
# Finally we merge that with the original urban dataframe
# so that each entry has its own LAT and LON:
res <- merge(res, urban, by="ID")
res
#         ID   pm       time      LAT      LON
#1    111121   42 2012030101 37.56464 126.9760
#2    111121   36 2012030102 37.56464 126.9760
#3    111121   46 2012030103 37.56464 126.9760
#4    111121   40 2012030104 37.56464 126.9760
#5    111121   36 2012030105 37.56464 126.9760
#...
#5995 831154   81 2012030119 37.52662 126.8064
#5996 831154   72 2012030120 37.52662 126.8064
#5997 831154   81 2012030121 37.52662 126.8064
#5998 831154   70 2012030122 37.52662 126.8064
#5999 831154   74 2012030123 37.52662 126.8064
#6000 831154   74 2012030124 37.52662 126.8064
```

250 urban sites X 24 hours = 6 000 datapoints, which is indeed what we get here.

Comment: Thank you @plannapus. thanks to R community for inspire me about R. and could you please suggest me that what should I learn more for this type of data management? recently I am trying to learn apply family. Some people say about 'plyr' package instead of apply family. what do you think?

Comment: Being a `base` purist, I would think that you should first learn to use the `apply` family and then, if you want, `plyr`: it's true that more and more people are using it, so you should at least be familiar with it to understand their code, and I'm sure there was a way to do what i did in this answer in just a one-liner with plyr (instead of `lapply`,  `do.call` and then `merge`, one could have use directly `ddply` I think) :)

Comment: Thank you so much @plannapus. I am getting a fan of this webpage and probably for next few months I will continuously disturb you guys by my silly question. sorry in advance.